# How to correctly use a LAN with network cables in walls?

Tags: networking, lan, home-networking, fritzbox

I just moved into a new apartment, and have problems connecting to the internet. Every room as a LAN outlet that looks like this:

[image]

The cables to these outlets run in the walls, and collectively have outlets in a central box in one wall that looks like this (bottom of the picture shows the cable outlets.

[image]

We have a FRITZ Box that is connected to the fibre optic cable network. Connecting to the internet via WiFi works fine; the same holds for connecting via putting a LAN cable directly in the router /FRITZ Box. What I have problem with is connecting to the internet via the LAN outlets shown in the first picture.

So what I did first was this

`Router (FRITZ Box) -- Cat 5 LAN cable -- outlet -- (walls) -- outlet -- Cat 5 LAN cable -- PC`

That did not work. I called some number I had from the internet company, who told me to do it like this:

`Router (FRITZ Box) -- Cat 7 LAN cable -- outlet -- (walls) -- outlet -- Cat 5 LAN cable -- PC`

which, however, also doesn't work. I have tried all combinations to make sure that there is no mis-labeling, and have tested all cables by directly connecting to the FRITZ box

So what can I do to fix this problem? Might there be a problem with the cables / connection in the walls?

Comment: Either of those setups would work just fine. Try hooking up a laptop or computer directly to the router to eliminate the wall cables as an issue.

Comment: There are 4 lower jacks that need to be plugged into the router.  Second, how many LAN jack are in the apartment total?  If more than 4 then there is another panel some where else in the apartment you need to find and connect.  If your whole apartment has 4 RJ45 jacks then you need a tester.

Comment: @CConard96 I tried that, and that worked without problems

Comment: @cybernard The jacks are the things in the bottom of the picture I connected to the router with a Cat 5/7 cable, right? Do they all need to be plugged into the router simultaneously? I only tried one line at a time thus far. Further, I believe there are only 3 RJ45 jacks in the apartment (not 4)

Comment: you don't have to connect all 4, you can test one by one. connect a cable from Fritz LAN (choose any of the 1-4) and connect it to the first connector below the FritzBox. Check your computer which you have connected to the wanted wall outlet. If it does not work try the next socket below the FritzBox until you get a connection. If none will work move your pc to the next wall socket and repeat. If the will not work, ask a techie who has a LAN checker to find out which wall outlet goes to which connector below the FritzBox and if all the cables in the walls are correctly connected.

Comment: @Zina Thanks, thats what I did (with one wall socket only though). I will proceed to test the other ones